How to access the name of a file A in file B where file B is imported into in file A
I have a file that I have been importing into my homeworks that has several functions, one of which is
def PDF(input_file:str, output_file:str):
    CODE TO MAKE A PDF OUT OF THE FILE I NEED TO TURN IN

I would like to be able to just run PDF with no arguments and have it just choose the file it has been imported into and create an output file with the same name, but file extension .pdf.
I'd like as little code as possible to be in file A so that each time I need to use file B, the extra code is minimal.
I tried using name and file and code similar to
def get_caller_filename():
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    file_name = frame.f_code.co_filename
    return file_name

but they all return file B (the one I'm importing).
Thank you in advance!!

import os
import inspect

def PDF(input_file=None, output_file=None):
    if input_file is None:
        frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
        input_file = frame.f_code.co_filename

    if output_file is None:
        output_file = os.path.splitext(input_file)[0] + '.pdf'

    print(f"Created PDF file: {output_file}")

# Simple call

# PDF() no args


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You could use following code to achieve it:
import os
import inspect

def get_caller_filename():
    return inspect.stack()[1].filename

def PDF(input_file: str | None = None, output_file: str | None = None):
    input_file = input_file or get_caller_filename()
    output_file = output_file or os.path.splitext(input_file)[0] + '.pdf'
    print(f"Creating PDF from {input_file},saving as {output_file}")

PDF()

